# Push Topic Creation issue for AccountContactRole object

Tags: streaming-api, pushtopic

To get updates from salesforce **Account, Contact and AccountContacRole objects** into my **local database**. I have create **pushTopic** for **Account and Contact object** and receiving update messages using JAVA streaming client successfully. 
But when I was creating pushTopic for **AccountContactRole object** using following query in developer console.

`PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'ACRoleTableStreaming';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT AccountId,ContactId,IsDeleted,IsPrimary,Role FROM AccountContactRole';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 30.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationCreate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUndelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationDelete = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;`

I am getting following Error message.
**12:59:29:065 EXCEPTION_THROWN [10]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, 'AccountContactRole' is not supported: [Query]**

FYI I am using **salesforce developer account** and have also tries creating above pushTopic using https://workbench.developerforce.com.  **And Still gote same Error. i.e. "Error Creating Push Topic:
'AccountContactRole' is not supported."**
**Can anyone please tell me how can I create pushTopic for AccountContaactRole object 
or 
how can I get real time updates from this object into my local database using salesforce Streaming Client or any other method ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not supported with the Streaming API.  From the [Streaming API Docs (v30)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/api_streaming.pdf):

> All custom objects are supported in PushTopic queries. **The following subset of standard objects are supported in PushTopic queries: Account, Campaign, Case, Contact, Lead, Opportunity, Task**. The following standard objects are supported in PushTopic queries through a pilot program: ContractLineItem, Entitlement, LiveChatTranscript, Quote, QuoteLineItem, ServiceContract.

You also cannot do relationships in a PushTopic query, so you can't simply look at Accounts with all children AccountContactRoles.

Another common pattern is to make a shadow object of AccountContactRoles for push notifications, but that's not possible since you cannot create a trigger on that object.

It looks like polling with a pull operation might be your best bet here.